# Script não mostra o caminho inteiro

Tags: shell, path

#### Código:

```
for i in `find $1 -name $4 -type f` ; do  
path=`readlink -f $4`  
words=`cat "$i" | wc -w`  
echo "$path: $words palavras"  
done
```

#### Imprime:

```
/home/miglui/Desktop/SO/teste.txt: 14 palavras  
/home/miglui/Desktop/SO/teste.txt: 48 palavras  
/home/miglui/Desktop/SO/teste.txt: 29 palavras
```

#### Devia Imprimir:

```
/home/miglui/Desktop/SO/teste/1/teste.txt: 14 palavras  
/home/miglui/Desktop/SO/teste/2/teste.txt: 48 palavras  
/home/miglui/Desktop/SO/teste/teste.txt: 29 palavras
```

O código não está a imprimir o caminho inteiro dos ficheiros. Onde poderá ser o erro?

Comment: pq vc nao faz ``path=`pwd $4```?

Comment: @lucas-virgili Porque tem de mostrar o nome do ficheiro no fim do caminho.

Answer (score 1):

Quando você chama a seguinte linha do script:

```
path=$(readlink -f $4)
```

Você está usando o argumento $4. Apesar de você não ter colocado um exemplo de chamada para esse script, creio que o argumento $4 é o nome do arquivo (exemplo: teste.txt). Só o nome do arquivo não vai servir. Tem que ser o caminho do arquivo achado pelo find.

No caso, você tem que indicar a linha:

```
path=$(readlink -f $i)
```

Já que o $i é a variável da iteração que contém o caminho completo do arquivo, e é o que você usa corretamente para contar a quantidade de palavras com o *wc*.

Answer (score 0):

Tenta

```
x=$"$(find -type f)"
for i in $x
    do echo -n "$i: "
    wc -w $i|cut -d " " -f1 -z
    echo -n " palavras"
    echo
done
```